# The ouput of the code is 3. Can someone explain how?

Tags: python

```
def my_fun(x):     
    z = 0     
    for item in x:         
       m = x.count(item)         
       if m > z:             
           z = m     
       return z  

y = ["cat", 4, "dog" , "cat" , 2, "cat", 2] 
print (my_fun(y))
```

The ouput of the code is `3`. Can someone explain how?

Comment: Maybe you meant to unindent the return statement? It would still return 3, though

Comment: The output would be `3`, too.

Comment: Visualize your code execution at [http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop immediately returns because the return statement is inside the for loop, and `z = m` is executed.

Even if the return was outside the loop, you'd still have 3 because cat appears that may times in the list and has the most occurrences.

You essentially have this single line of code

```
print( ["cat", 4, "dog" , "cat" , 2, "cat", 2].count("cat"))
```

I trust you can see why that outputs 3. It's not clear what else you expected